# Duplicate Open Graph and Twitter Share metatags with Joomla5, Flexicontent

Tags: joomla-4.x, flexicontent

I'm currently working on a website running Joomla version 5.0.2 and utilizing Flexicontent (version 4.2.1) to manage its content. For the creation of social share buttons for each item, I'm using the Flexicontent Toolbar plugin, which also generates Open Graph and Twitter meta tags. Additionally, I have the 4SEF plugin for managing SEF URLs.

However, I've encountered an issue where duplicate Open Graph and Twitter meta tags are being generated. This problem is causing inaccuracies when sharing content on social media platforms, as it displays the wrong item's content on Facebook or Twitter. I've provided as much information as I can, and I'm seeking assistance in resolving this issue.